# pandas aggregate count higher than threshold

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

I have a data frame that I want to groupby. I want to use df.agg to determine the length that exceed above 180.

Is there a possible way to write a small function for it?

I tried `len(nice_numbers[nice_numbers > 180])` but it did not work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'nice_numbers': [60, 64, 67, 70, 73, 75, 130, 180, 184, 186, 187, 187, 188, 194, 199, 195, 200, 210, 220, 222, 224, 250, 70, 40, 30, 300], 'activity': 'sleeping', 'sleeping', 'sleeping', 'walking', 'walking', 'walking', 'working', 'working', 'working', 'working', 'working', 'restaurant', 'restaurant', 'restaurant', 'restaurant', 'walking', 'walking', 'walking', 'working', 'working', 'driving', 'driving', 'driving', 'home', 'home', 'home}')
df_gb = df.groupby('activity')
df_gb.agg({'count_frequency_over_180'})
```

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create boolean mask by compare column by [`gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.gt.html) with aggregate `sum` for count `True`s values:

```
df1 = (df['nice_numbers'].gt(180)
                         .groupby(df['activity'], sort=False)
                         .sum()
                         .astype(int)
                         .reset_index())
```

Similar solution with `sum` by index created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('activity')['nice_numbers'].gt(180).sum(level=0).astype(int).reset_index()
print (df1)
     activity  nice_numbers
0    sleeping             0
1     walking             3
2     working             5
3  restaurant             4
4     driving             2
5        home             1
```

EDIT:

For more metrics for `nice_numbers` column use [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
agg = ('abobe_180_count', lambda x: x.gt(180).sum()), ('average', 'mean')
df1 = df.groupby('activity')['nice_numbers'].agg(agg).reset_index()
print (df1)
     activity  abobe_180_count     average
0     driving                2  181.333333
1        home                1  123.333333
2  restaurant                4  192.000000
3    sleeping                0   63.666667
4     walking                3  137.166667
5     working                5  187.000000
```

For multiple threshold use:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'threshold':[180, 270, 60]})
print (df1.head())
   threshold
0        180
1        270
2         60

#compare values by numpy broadcasting
arr = df['nice_numbers'].to_numpy()[:, None] > df1['threshold'].to_numpy()

#create new DataFrame and add column activity
df2 = (pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df.index, columns=df1['threshold'].tolist())
         .assign(activity = df['activity']))
print (df2.head())
     180    270     60  activity
0  False  False  False  sleeping
1  False  False   True  sleeping
2  False  False   True  sleeping
3  False  False   True   walking
4  False  False   True   walking

#aggregate sum
df3 = df2.groupby('activity', as_index=False).sum()
print (df3)
     activity  180  270  60
0     driving    2    0   3
1        home    1    1   1
2  restaurant    4    0   4
3    sleeping    0    0   2
4     walking    3    0   6
5     working    5    0   7
```

Comment: you are always the best @jazrael but what if I already calculated other metrics like mean, standard deviation within the aggregate function? I have more calculations to make I would have to write a small function to execute it

Comment: Is there a way to extend this solution to multiple thresholds?

Comment: To clarify, I mean, I'd like a `threshold` column e.g. 180, 270, 360, and I'd like the other column to read `threshold_count`, indicating for the row's threshold, how many elements in that group were above the threshold

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer - answer was edited.